# Prevent org-mode from normalizing links

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Org-mode insists on normalizing links (and it does it wrong!) Example link:

```
[[../file.ext][The file]]
```

is transformed into

```
[[file:~/in/the/galaxy/far/far/away/file.ext][The file]]
```

Of course, after copying generated HTML, the link is broken. Is there any way to inhibit this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at (or set) the variable org-link-file-path-type?